# Setting Up Git Server with Web interface

Tags: git, version-control

I've installed git on Ubuntu server under apache using WebDav. Now when I access the web over 127.0.0.1/myproject.git, I see directories and files of git i.e. branches, config, descrption, info, ref etc.

I've installed git-core and gitweb, but still I'm not able to see code that is committed on web and neither I'm able to see there revisions. What do I need to do so that I can see all these files of the code and can navigate through them as well as see latest commits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

gitweb should give you a view to what you need. Ensure that you have it set up correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer. I need install ViewVC or Rhodecode